# How to make FomrGroup readonly in Angular8 without the disabled() function?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

A FormGroup is either filled directly from UrlQuery Parameters or by user input. When the UrlQuery Parameters are provided, the FormGroup should be readonly. I saw the `disable()` function, but this is not working for me because the values of the FormGroup are not submitted. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide some code if you still want an answer

Answer (score 0):

use add the readonly property to the input tag:

`<input controlName="Example" readonly></input>`

resource:
- https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_readonly.asp